# XSLT: read value (Not Attribute) of other node based on current context

Tags: html, xml, xslt

I need help with selecting values from matching nodes.
Need to get employee info matching name from CompanyTable against EmployeeTable

Output Expected

```
John 1034 ABC Corp
Smith 1449 Fox Corp
Adam 1664 CNN Corp
```

```html
    <Main>
        <EmployeeTable>
            <Employees>
                <ID>1034</ID>
                <name>John</name>
            </Employees>
            <Employees>
                <ID>1449</ID>
                <name>Smith</name>
            </Employees>
            <Employees>
                <ID>1664</ID>
                <name>Adam</name>
            </Employees>
        </EmployeeTable>
        <CompanyTable>
            <Companies>
                <Company>ABC Corp</Company>
                <Employee>John</Employee>
            </Companies>
            <Companies>
                <Company>Fox Corp</Company>
                <Employee>Smith</Employee>
            </Companies>
            <Companies>
                <Company>CNN Corp</Company>
                <Employee>Adam</Employee>
            </Companies>
        </CompanyTable>
    </Main>
```

Comment: Your output contains no data from the `CompanyTable` section.

Comment: True, I corrected the output. Please see now. thank you again.